# does installing libraries makes linux slower

Tags: linux, 64-bit, libraries

I have ubuntu amd64, and i want to install packet tracer on it. the thing is, packet tracer requires a lot of 32 bits libraries to work.

So, does installing a lot of libraries makes linux slower or less reactive, or it doesn't affect it in anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Libraries are just files on your disk, they do nothing until you start a program that uses them. They won't get automatically loaded into *all* programs (that would be very useless). Therefore just having them installed shouldn't affect anything else.

However, some *package managers* might get slower if you have too many packages installed. I think Debian's `apt-get` used to get slower over time.

---

Also, sometimes programs drag in various other dependencies – including services, not just libraries. (For example, media players might pull in avahi-daemon or something.) On some distributions like Debian, services get started by default when installed (even if not really needed), so that might also make things slower.

(Although even *that* shouldn't make general usage slower. Even if useless junk takes time to *start*, normally it *doesn't* use any CPU when running idle.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i guess that installed libraries creates (or extract) a lot of files in the system, isn't having a lot of inodes in the system slows him down ??

Comment: A lot of inodes doesn't mean anything. A lot of inodes _within the same directory_ can affect the speed of path lookups, so that might be an issue for `/usr/lib` (where all libraries go), but on modern filesystems like ext4 or btrfs (and with the kernel keeping parts of the directory cached in RAM), I think you'd need many thousand files to even notice a difference.